# Huge memory leak after using MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management, memory-leaks, instruments

I've come across this 3MB malloc done by CoreVideo on my iPad app after releasing an MPMoviePlayerController object.

I've made sure that the player is stopped before released, so it does actually release memory and deallocs properly. The thing is that instruments keeps showing this malloc that hasn't been released (and is not used directly by me in my code)
This is the call that's shown in instruments as responsible caller for the 3.52MB Malloc that's never released.

```
CVPixelBufferBacking::initWithPixelBufferDescription
```

Here's the code where the players are stopped and the array that contains them released

```
- (void)dealloc {
...


[self stopAllPlayers];
[_moviePlayerViewControllerArray release];

[super dealloc];
}

-(void)stopAllPlayers {
    for (MPMoviePlayerController *mp in _moviePlayerViewControllerArray) {
        [mp stop];

    }
}
```

here's the method that adds the video

```
-(void)addVideo:(NSString*) videoName onRect:(CGRect)rect {



 ......

    MPMoviePlayerController * movieController= [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL:(NSURL *)videoURL];

    // set frame for player
    movieController.view.frame = rect;

    // set  auto resizing masks
    [movieController.view setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];

    // don't auto play.
    [movieController setShouldAutoplay:NO];

    [pdfView addSubview:movieController.view];
    [pdfView bringSubviewToFront: movieController.view];


    [_moviePlayerViewControllerArray addObject:movieController];
    [movieController release];

}
```

EDIT: added image[image: instruments zombies on simulator (obviously)]. the beautiful 3MB malloc in all it's glory.

[image: This other screenshot is the allocations instruments running on the ipad.e]
as you can see the other chunk of memory is no longer there but I still have a major problem.
thanks in advance for your help

Comment: please update your question with your code snippet and instrument screen shot  also, maybe i help you.

Comment: Hey, I just added snippets and screenshot! :-)

Comment: did you test it on a device or in the simulator ? I think there are some differences in the case of the movie controller.

Comment: indeed you are right.  I have now a huge block of 8MB of CoreGraphics which responsible caller is CGDataProviderCreateWithFileName

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally nailed this issue. When I tested out the app on the device, what was supposed to be a leak on CoreVideo changed its name to "". Lurking a little bit around certain forums, I found this is cause mainly by Core Graphic "objects" being autoreleased but never deallocated by the auto release pool.

Basically Wherever I created and used Core Graphics objects, I added NSAutoReleasePool objects to dispose the CG objects in a timely manner.

Thank you very much for you answers. And specially to Bastian for his comment on my question that was key to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

do you do

```
[movieController.view removeFromSuperview]
```

somewhere ?

Comment: Nope, I just release it. I'm gonna give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

add a movie finished callback this way -

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(movieFinishedCallback:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:[playerViewController moviePlayer]];
```

and release and remove the player in this callback method -

```
- (void) movieFinishedCallback:(NSNotification*) aNotification {
MPMoviePlayerController *player1 = [aNotification object];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification  object:player];
    [player1 stop];
    [player1.view removeFromSuperview];
    [player1 release];
}
```

Comment: why would you remove it when it finished playback? it might be in fullscreen mode which would not look nice if immidiatly removed or maybe it should be possible to watch the movie a second time...

Comment: I don't want to remove the view controller when its finished playing the movie.

Comment: then it will leak your memory because you are referencing it after movie is finished

Comment: yes... it violates the memory management rule that "removeFromSuperview" will also release the object and then if we release it again then it will throw the exc bad access but its working ... I also wondered on it!!